# How to clear out a wallet

Tags: mist

I am busy practicing writing contracts on the test network and I have a quesiton about how to empty a wallet.

This is what I have done:

1. I created a new test wallet
2. I sent it ETH 100
3. I now want to send the ETH100 back to the original wallet

There is an option called: "Send Everything", however, how do I pay for GAS using this method?

If GAS should be included in the transaction, should mist not take this into account?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Inferring from [this mist bug report](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/356), "Send Everything" should calculate the fees you need to complete your transaction.  So that function should indeed completely empty your wallet.